# Polyfill for Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, polyfills

I'm using [Tagify](https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/) in my project and its working in chrome. Now I want it to work in IE9 too. So I added the polyfill that the plugin provided but it keep show error in the tagify.min.js for this line:

`parseHTML:function(t){return(new DOMParser).parseFromString(t.trim(),"text/html").body.firstElementChild}`

I'd be grateful for any pointers. Below is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tagify/tagify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tagify/tagify.polyfills.min.js"></script>
...
<input style="width: 200px;" name="txtFormPickup"/> 
...
var inputElm = document.querySelector('input[name=txtFormPickup]');
var tagify = new Tagify(inputElm, {});
tagify.addTags([{value:"banana", color:"yellow"}, {value:"apple", color:"red"}, {value:"watermelon", color:"green"}]);
```

Comment: If you think that moving to IE 11 browser can help the code to work and it can fix the issue then I suggest you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the sample code and it looks like it can only work with the IE 10 and IE 11 version.

code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.polyfills.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <input style="width: 200px;" name="txtFormPickup"/> 
      <script>
         var inputElm = document.querySelector('input[name=txtFormPickup]');
         var tagify = new Tagify(inputElm, {});
         tagify.addTags([{value:"banana", color:"yellow"}, {value:"apple", color:"red"}, {value:"watermelon", color:"green"}]);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output in the IE 11 with different document modes:

[image]

In the documentation of **[Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify)**, they did not clearly mention that with which version of the IE their polyfill can work. So I suggest you move to IE 11 browser that may help to fix the issue.

IE 9 is a too old version and out of support scope of the Microsoft.